# Android application that sends data to all application holders

Tags: android, database, notifications, information-retrieval

I have this application that notifies its registered users on updates about something...but the things is that I don't know how to send that data as a notification to all of the applications users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send data as notifications to users you could use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM).

With GCM users can automatically register with you when they first run the application. You save their unique id in a database somewhere and then you can use these ID's to send messages (data) to the Google servers who will then push this data to the Android devices.

To read more about GCM and how to implement it check out the Android Developers site: http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html